# SSRS alternate row colors with column groups

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have reports in SSRS where I'm able to alternate the row colors using this expression:

```
=IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "LightSteelBlue","WhiteSmoke")
```

This works great.  However, I have a report that has a column grouping, and this seems to mess up the alternating row colors.

[image: Report Image]

The grouped columns will alternate column colors instead of row colors.  I've searched and found possible solutions with row groupings but nothing with column groupings, or at least nothing I can get to work.  I'm just trying to have every other row be "LightSteelBlue" or "WhiteSmoke," nothing fancy.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've always found it annoying to alternate the row color in SSRS.  Perhaps try placing the expression higher up on the row groupings (I believe that's the right terminology - it's been a little bit since I've used SSRS)

Comment: Can you only alternate the main group? Or are you trying to have the alternation apply with child groups as well?

Comment: Only the main group is alternating.  The column grouping is part of the row so the color needs to match the rest of the row.  I can't put the expression higher on the row groupings because there is only one row grouping.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution that I came up with:

1. Add a column to the right end of the table and name the text box "RowNumber."  Set the visibility to Hidden.
2. Add expression to RowNumber text box.

   ```
    =RunningValue(Fields!last_name.Value & Fields!entity_name.Value, CountDistinct, "dataset name")
   ```
3. Add expression to Background Color of the Details Row:

   ```
   =IIF(ReportItems!RowNumber.Value mod 2 > 0, "LightSteelBlue", "WhiteSmoke")
   ```

The RunningValue() function needs unique values.  In my case the member name can be repeated several times due to one member belonging to different entities.  Therefore I combined last_name and entity_name to get a unique value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also have combined the two expressions, that way you would not need to add a column.
`=IIf(RUNNINGVALUE(Fields!last_name.Value & Fields!entity_name.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) MOD 2, "LightSteelBlue","WhiteSmoke")`

Answer (score 0):

Try using runningvalue instead of rownumber where the field name is the field in your details row:

=iif(VAL(runningvalue(fields!yourfield.Value,countdistinct,nothing)) MOD 2, "LightBlueSteel", "WhiteSmoke")

Comment: If I populate fields!yourField.Value with the row grouping of LastName, the colors only alternate when the last name changes, which doesn't work since I have records where the same person is repeated.  If I use the column grouping of StatusName it only changes the top rows to blue and the rest are all white.